# Render view mode not rendering, instead showing outline only

Tags: objects, gpu

[image]

here is what it looks like when I switch to render view mode. This is a rendering of the default cube. I have an rx580 and an AMD Ryzen 5 3600 and 16GB of ddr4 ram, clocked at 3000MHZ. I have tried switching between different blender versions, yet still no hope. I have also change the render engine to open cl, selecting only my GPU for computing